# Stuck on making an array with its items from an SQL query

Tags: php, sql, arrays, while-loop

Basically i wont to be able to grab all items and insert them into an array at the moment i have made Category arrays but i cant seem to get all the items in the array only one item is going into each section

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM products group by Market ";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

// GETS all Category
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM products group by Category";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$array = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $array[$row['Category']] =  array();
}

while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {

    $array[$row['Category']] =  array($row['Market']);
}
```

At the moment it outputs

[image: array of my categories with one item]

But there are more items for each category for example looking at the SQL there are 2 markets for camcorders, it seems to me its not looping all the sub categories or overwriting them

```
SELECT * FROM products where Category = 'CAMCORDERS' group by Market
```

[image: query of camcorders]

Comment: Well, you only assign one item to one key. Perhaps you want to **append to an array..!?** `$array[$row['Category']][] = ..`

Comment: @deceze thankyou this worked!!